# How to fix corrupt video caused by amix filter - FFMPEG

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I am trying to put text and audio in a video using FFMPEG. It is weird because the output is corrupted and the video timeline stop counting the video time currently playing. And also, some portions of the video are missing and even freezing/hanging.

I already tried to search for this including updating my computers OS (Centos 7). Also, updating, upgrading ffmpeg build in my unit but still no luck.

I am generating the video using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-i mouse_click.mp3 \
-i typing.mp3 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]drawbox=enable='between(t,84,87)':y=ih-ih/5:color=black@1.0:width=iw:height=72:t=max,drawbox=enable='between(t,97,102)':y=ih-ih/5:color=black@1.0:width=iw:height=72:t=max,drawbox=enable='between(t,100,101)':x=622:y=682:w=93:h=31:color=red,drawtext=enable='between(t,84,86)':fontfile=fonts/RobotoBoldCondensed.ttf:text='Enter "admin-pc"...':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=50:y=h-h/5+20,drawtext=enable='between(t,98,99)':fontfile=fonts/RobotoBoldCondensed.ttf:text='Finding "Use express settings"...':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=50:y=h-h/5+20,drawtext=enable='between(t,100,101)':fontfile=fonts/RobotoBoldCondensed.ttf:text='Text Found':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=50:y=h-h/5+20[video];[1]adelay=102000|102000,volume=15dB[s1];[2]adelay=84000|84000,volume=15dB[s0];[s0][s1] amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,dynaudnorm [click_sound]" \
-map "[video]" \
-map "[click_sound]" \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a mp3 output.mp4
```

I tried to remove the audio script by removing these lines:

[1]adelay=102000|102000,volume=15dB[s1];
   [2]adelay=84000|84000,volume=15dB[s0];
   [s0][s1] amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,dynaudnorm  [click_sound]

and removing the

-map "[click_sound]"

, the video is working fine and is not corrupted. I believe it is becuase of the **amix** filter or something else but I cannot figure it out.

The output should be a working video.

Any response will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're using an older version of ffmpeg. Get a static binary from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ and check

Comment: @Gyan - thank you for your response. I will try it

Comment: @Gyan - I downloaded one package but still it doesn't resolve my problem. I guess the problem is with vnc2flv